# PHP PDO - Inserting into table with foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, phpmyadmin

I want to insert into a table called Festivals that has two foreign keys (venueID & ticketID).

The SQL:

```
$addFestivalSql = "INSERT INTO festivals 
                        VALUES(DEFAULT, :festivalName, :festivalDescription, 
                                :festivalImage, :festivalLineup, 
                                :musicTypeId, DEFAULT,  DEFAULT)";
```

The error:

Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

The Festivals Table:

The Festivals Table

[image]

I've created the two foreign key constraints with venueID and ticketID relating to the two primary keys.

Why do you think I'm getting this error?

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot set a DEFAULT value for the 2 id's that are foreign keys

Comment: The owning rows must exist before the child row can be created, and you must enter the relevant keys in these 2 columns

Comment: @RiggsFolly - oh I see, how would I insert therefore the IDs since they are going to hopefully auto increment?

Comment: Well you either need to know then or go and find them

Comment: Actually as I assume you woudl want to create the Festival Record before selling Tickets for the Festival I would guess the `ticketID` does not want to be a Foreign Key of even a field in this table

Comment: Thanks, that worked.